# HELO using a mailfilter

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exchange

We have a 2013 Exchange server and use a mailfilter that scans incoming and outgoing mail.
A clients email server rejected our messages saying that they don't accept email if the "forward-confirmed reverse DNS lookup" is different.

I think it's due to the fact that our exchange server is "EXCHANGE-SERVER.company.com"
Our mailfilter is MAILFILTER.company.com and holds the mx records for company.com

How can I correct this so the HELO record shows correctly? Is there a DNS record I should be looking at? Or could the issue lie in a send connector?

Comment: Just to let everyone know I found the issue was a result of email outbound was using a different IP address then Inbound email thus causing this issue. It was a fix done in our NAT policy. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages you're seeing are probably not related to your HELO, but to your DNS setup.
When your mailfilter connects to a remote site that remote site does a reverse lookup on your IP address (which *should* resolve to "mailfilter.company.com"). This part is the "reverse lookup".

After that the result of that first query is put into a forward lookup and the expected result is your IP address again. This part is the "forward-confirming".

Just make sure that the forward- and reverse-lookup for the Host/IP that sends mail is consistent and this error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the ehlo in the send connector details in your exchange Server.

**Exchange 2016:**
[image]

**Exchange 2010:**

[image]